# Interpret 'collection' in db.collection.drop() as variable vs. set database

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to iterate through a list of collections within a MongoDB 3.4 database and perform updates and deletions.  I'm trying to make the code interpret 'collection' as a string variable, but the code believes it is a single database:

```
for collection in db.collection_names():
    if collection[-3:] == "_CS":
        request = [UpdateMany({},{"$set": {"Collection": collection}})]
        result = db.collection.bulk_write(request)

    else:
        db.collection.drop()
```

Is there an alternative way to delete a collection through Python/Pymongo that takes the name of the collection as an argument, or is there a way to parse 'collection' so that the interpreter realizes it's a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop block the `collection` name is bound to a `str` object.

Dictionary style indexing is useful here to access the collection with the `collection` name. *e.g.*

```
for collection in db.collection_names():
    if collection[-3:] == "_CS":
        request = [UpdateMany({},{"$set": {"Collection": collection}})]
        result = db[collection].bulk_write(request)

    else:
        db[collection].drop()
```

Or, use the `get_collection` method of the `pymongo.database.Database` instance.

```
for collection in db.collection_names():
    if collection[-3:] == "_CS":
        request = [UpdateMany({},{"$set": {"Collection": collection}})]
        result = db.get_collection(collection).bulk_write(request)

    else:
        db.get_collection(collection).drop()
```